# Only Else is executing even "result" is not true

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have made a locator that indicates the disable button and put that in condition like, refresh the page and wait for 15 sec in else if result is true, and if result is not true that execute the if statement. But its keep executing else statement.

```
static async waitForButtonToBeEnabledAndThenClickToDownload(id: string, classAttr: string) {
    await ElementHelper.isElementDisplayed(CompliancePolicyManagementPage.locatorByIdAndDisabledAttribute(id)).then(function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (result != true) {
                CommonPageHelper.clickByIdandClass(id, classAttr);
                WaitHelper.getInstance().staticWait(1000);
                console.log('Value of Result should be false: ' + result);
                break;
            }
            else {
                WaitHelper.getInstance().staticWait(15000);
                CommonPageHelper.refreshPage();
                console.log('Value of Result: ' + result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

if result is true then else statement will be executed and if it is not true then if statement will be executed and function should be terminated

Comment: You're not changing the value of `result` inside your loop…

Comment: `break;` should work - maybe you are confused because it runs 10 times? try `i = 11` before `break;` for debugging

Comment: I was also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one

```
static async waitForButtonToBeEnabledAndThenClickToDownload(id: string, classAttr: string) {
    await ElementHelper.isElementDisplayed(CompliancePolicyManagementPage.locatorByIdAndDisabledAttribute(id)).then(function (result) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (result != true) {
                CommonPageHelper.clickByIdandClass(id, classAttr);
                WaitHelper.getInstance().staticWait(1000);
                console.log('Value of Result should be false: ' + result);
                break;
            }
                WaitHelper.getInstance().staticWait(15000);
                CommonPageHelper.refreshPage();
                console.log('Value of Result: ' + result);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks :), It was a silly mistake by the way I couldn't able to find at that time, Thanks

Comment: Mark the answer as correct.If it had helped you to find the mistake. Thanks